# Cancel Form without validation

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have an HTML Form which has two Buttons of the type "submit". One for submitting the form and one for cancelling the form.

[image]

To validate the input, I added a event listener, which reacts when somebody submits the form:

```
    $("form").submit(function (e) {
    if (textboxContainsValues){
       return true:
    }
       else false;
    });
```

My problem is, when I click on "Cancel" (abbrechen), it also goes into the event listener and checks the textboxes for values.

Is there a way to distinguish those two actions with my above listener?

thanks in advance

Comment: What is `:`  in `true:`? Do you use Developer Tools? What do you think `else false;` does? Should be `return false;` Cancel button as - submit?

Comment: `return false` instead of just `false`

Comment: Actually your entire function's body can simply be: `return textboxContainsValues;`

Comment: Both your buttons are `type="submit"` so of course they both trigger the `submit` event. Use `type="button"` for your cancel button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments you could either simplify your function to just `return textboxContainsValues;` or even better use `type="button"` instead of `type="submit"` on your cancel button.